# JS/html: keep some margin from the anchor?

Tags: javascript, html

is it possible to jump give url like test.php#first
and make the page jump soem pixel before the actual anchor position?

i dont need animation or jquery transition, I just need to jump the user to the anchor but I dont want to keep a margin from top

i hope i was clear..

Answer (score -1):

`<a name="first"></a>`

I'm not sure what you mean by keeping a margin from the top..